# Infinitely scrollable list

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, viewpagerindicator, kotlin-android

Please tell me if there are already existing good libraries of horizontally infinitely scrollable scrollers, preferably with an indicator display at the bottom. I have found several implementations, but I would like it to be implemented using ViewPager, not RecyclerView. We need a scroller as simple as possible. If you have examples of solutions, or know such libraries, then please share.

Comment: Are looking paging with viewpager!?

Comment: Yes. Android itself does not provide the possibility of endless scrolling. And this functionality can be implemented either using RecyclerViewe or ViewPager. If it's simple, then everything works as follows: there is a list [a, b, c], we add fake pages to the beginning and end, i.e. there will be [c, a, b, c, a], and if the user reaches the last element, then when scrolling it will redirect to the first page and vice versa. And I need a reliable library.

Comment: If you're adding more bulk dots at the time dots also scrollable right.
Is it minimal items or more than 20 will appear?